# Match only the second and subsequent hyphens in a regex

Tags: r, regex

My goal is to match ONLY the hyphens in a string after the first one so I can remove them with null spaces in R.

Example:

`This test - and it is a test - should work - very well.`

Desired outcome:

`This test - and it is a test  should work  very well.`

I've tried `(?<=\-).*?\-` but that matches the contents between the hyphens as well. The string may have a variable number of hyphens, but I only want to preserve the first one.

What should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do it this way:

```
string <- "This test - and it is a test - should work - very well."

gsub("^([^-]*\\-)|\\-", "\\1", string, perl=TRUE)

[1] "This test - and it is a test  should work  very well."
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `SKIP/FAIL` to skip the first `-`

```
gsub("^[^-]+-(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\s*-", "", str1, perl = TRUE)
```

-output

```
[1] "This test - and it is a test should work very well."
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "This test - and it is a test - should work - very well."
```